# How to use special characters in http response header

Tags: java, http, servlets

I will be very specific. I am building a web app using servlets. What I do is get an email object (Message) using javax.mail package, then I encapsulate this object in http response output stream. The purpose is that when pressing the specific button, the email will be downloaded in an eml format. So until this, it works. I use as file name the message subject. The problem is that when the email subject has characters like "€", the file is not downloaded. Instead, a service-request file is downloaded. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you could provide a code sample of your solution, we could help more.

Comment: If a `/` were in the subject, one would need to replace that anyway. So maybe better convert the name a bit.

Comment: account.checkStoreConnected();
   FolderCache mcache = account.getFolderCache(foldername);
   Message msg=mcache.getMessage(Long.parseLong(uid));
   String subject = msg.getSubject();
   String ctype = "application/octet-stream";
   response.setContentType(ctype);
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + subject + ".eml\"");
   OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
   msg.writeTo(out);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use non-ASCII-characters in Content-Disposition, you need to encode them. See RFC 6266, Sections 4.3 and 5, for details.

Comment: I read them but I am not being able to understand fully what I have to do

Comment: Did you look at the examples?

Comment: Yes I implemented it. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Question is a bit vague but try adding headers (response.getHeaders()) like charset, encoding and language

Answer (score -1):

I did implemented a download of eml files one day and the Content-Type to "application/mail". Please try this instead of "application/octet-stream".

Comment: Ok. Now i think the problem is not really the subject of your mail, but the filename of your eml file which you set to the subject. Please try it by changing the filename.

Comment: Yes the filename is the problem. Sorry for miss expressing. So the subject is set as filename and when the subject contains characters like "€" the file is not created properly.